# Can there be a relationship between 2 subclasses?

Tags: database, database-design, entity-relationship

Let's say I've got a superclass *E* and 2 subclasses *E1 and E2*. Can there be any relationship between E1 and E2 without any previous knowledge?

[image]

Comment: What does "without any previous knowledge" mean here?

Comment: What I mean by that is without knowing any other details regarding the rest of the ER diagram. I've also attached one example in the main post, mind checking it out?

Comment: What do you mean by "relationship"?--FK or association? Also, what is a reference for the notation in this diagram?--There are many conventions. PS Learn *what a diagram means*--how one is mapped to tables & constraints. In general constraints (diagrammable or not) can hold in addition to illustrated ones. But there are exceptions. Eg A CK has no proper subset as CK. We must be precise. Eg "many:many" implicitly continues "... but not 1:many". What diagrams mean depends on the design method & diagramming method, so your question can't be answered without a complete description of them.

Comment: In other words: A diagram describes a system. Contradictory properties can't hold; the diagram can't be added to in certain ways. But that doesn't stop you from saying that some other system you have in mind does or doesn't have more tables and/or constraints than the system in the diagram.

Comment: I might have been off with my question. I have yet to learn Foreign Keys, s association is the word I should have used

Answer (score 2):

This is not only possible, but also quite common. Consider for instance the class Employee with the subclasses Manager and Clerk, and an association describing the clerks managed by each manager.

Or a computer company that sells products (superclass) which can be either full computer or components (subclasses), where a computer is associated with the components from which it is built.

Comment: That's quite well put! Exactly what I was looking for! What if however, the relationship defined between the 2 subclasses has a cardinality of One-to-One, and they have the constraint of disjointness. This cannot be true right? And that's mainly because of the disjoint. Do I stand correctly? @Renzo

Comment: @VilleFTW, consider for instance an university in which a student (superclass) can be either a freshmen or an advanced student (subclasses) and where an advanced student can become a tutor of a (unique) freshmen. The association is one to one and the subclasses are disjoint. There is nothing in principle that prohibits associations of any type between subclasses of any kind.